# How to calculate the moment/torque at the center axis of a blade?

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil, blade

How do I calculate the moment/torque at the center axis (same plane with lift and drag force) of a blade with NACA airfoil standard when it is placed inside a wind tunnel or exposed to airflow?